# Obseravable Collection not updating ListView UI when changed (Prism for Xamarin Forms)

Tags: listview, data-binding, xamarin.forms, prism, observablecollection

I'm using Prism in my Xamarin Forms application.

I'm Binding a Observable Collection to a List View and when I refresh the data the View Model Collection updates with the new data but the UI is not updated.

After a bit of research I found that the collection only updates when items are added or removed.

```
public async Task RefeshEvents()
    {
        try
        {
            IsLoading = false;
            IsRefreshing = true;
            Events = await _eventService.GetEvents();
            IsRefreshing = false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await
                _pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Connection Error",
                    "We could not Connect to the internet please check your connection", "Ok");
            IsRefreshing = false;
        }

    }
```

As you can see I am assigning a new List to the Collection.

```
 private ObservableCollection<Event> _events;
    public ObservableCollection<Event> Events
    {
        get { return this._events; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _events, value); }
    }
```

Is there a way for me to update the UI without having to manually manage the list?

Comment: Please provide your Events property definition.

Comment: @BrianLagunas I have added the property definiton

Comment: @BrianLagunas my assumption was that BindableBase would invoke the PropertyChanged when I assign the new collection to the Viewmodel Property?

Answer (score 2):

If `Events` is the `ObservableCollection`, you have to raise a `NotifyProperty` for that property when you set it to a new value for the ui to update according to the new value, like any other property.

`ObservableCollection` updates the ui automatically when you *modify* the collection (i.e. add or remove elements), but when you *replace the whole collection*, you don't modify the collection but a property of your view model.

Comment: My ViewModel Inherits Bindable Base which in turn inherits the InotifyPropertyChanged interface so shouldnt the change in the Viewmodel property raise the NotifyProperty method?

Comment: Yes, it should do that. Posted my answer before your edit... but can you confirm the property is set to a new value actually (or does `GetEvents` always return the same collection)? And btw, why is it an `ObservableCollection` if you replace it as a whole?

Comment: Get events returns a new Collection and assigns it to the property. I agree theres now no need for the ObservableCollection after what you have explained in your answer